# release db connections in standalone application

Tags: spring, jpa, shutdown

I am working on a standalone application using Spring/JPA and I am trying to release properly the database resources used.

In a Web application using tomcat for example, we shutdown the server, and this way, we let Tomcat manage the resources.

But as I am in a standalone app, I have to take care about this, I use *Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook* to "catch" the shutdown event and call *((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();*, something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
    }
```

It works but with an exception in the stacktrace if a thread was using a connection.
I am wondering if there is another option? Maybe getting a list of open transactions and force them to rollback?

Comment: You didn't specify the version of Spring you're using, but perhaps this might help http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you would need to implement something like [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean) and inside your destroy method, you would retrieve your datasource and call a **close** method or something similar. I'm also assuming you have a few things to do when you shutdown your application.

I can't quite help with the right method name as I don't know what you are using for your datasource.